# Slim PHP framework 3.0: 404 error when accessing .phtml template routes

Tags: php, api, routes, http-status-code-404, slim

## Server configuration:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Apache 2.4.29
- PostgreSQL 10.6
- PHP 7.3 (I was using 7.2 but the system has decided to update it for me, I will rollback once I have resolved the current bugs)
- Composer
- Slim/Slim 3.0
- Slim/php-view

I have been building an API with the Slim PHP framework, using [gothinkster's repository](https://github.com/gothinkster/slim-php-realworld-example-app/) as a starting point. The code has been heavily adapted, though all code relating to rendering templates remains intact. When I access the website's homepage, the `index.phtml` file is rendered properly, but following any hyperlinks from th homepage results in a `404` error, although the `.phtml` files all reside within the same directory.

The following are excerpts of my code, excluding irrelevant configuration. Although I have only displayed one endpoint, the API defines 10 endpoints, all of which are get requests with no arguments, using `.phtml` files which reside within the same folder.

Settings, routes and dependencies are called using require statements within the `index.php` file.

### /[api_root]/public/index.php:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {

    $url  = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];

    if (is_file($file)) {

        return false;

    }
}

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';

$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

The settings file returns an array containing a reference to the template path.

### [api_root]/src/settings.php:

```
'settings' => [
    'renderer' => [
        'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/',
    ]
]
```

Templates are assigned to the renderer within the `dependencies.php` file.

### [api_root]/src/dependencies.php:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

// view renderer
$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['renderer'];
    return new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer($settings['template_path']);
};
```

`.phtml` templates are rendered within `get` requests.

### [api_root]/src/routes.php

```
$app->get('/getting-started',
    function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        return $this->renderer->render($response, 'getting-started.phtml');
    });
```

The `getting-started.phtml` file is located within `[api_root]/templates/`.

The root `/` is defined and successfully returns the `index.phtml` file located within the templates directory, but when I attempt to follow any links from the homepage, I recieve a `404` error. The anchor which points to the getting-started page successfully redirects to `mywebsiteurl.com/getting-started`, but the template file is not rendered and the browser responds with a `404` error.

All application files are stored privately on the server. I have created symlinks from the contents of the `[api_root]/public` folder to my website's `public_html` folder.

There is obviously something wrong with my definition of the path to the `/templates` directory, but I can't work out how to rectify it.

#### EDIT:

When I created the symlinks to the public_html folder, I had forgotten to include hidden files (namely, the `.htaccess` file). I have since created this symlink, though now when I attempt to access the homepage I see the default apache2 page which is displayed after apache is installed. I will note here that the website resides on a paid server. Apache is configured to use virtual hosts and I have edited the hosts file on my local machine properly. As stated, without an `.htaccess` file I can view the homepage, but other routes are not being found. When the `.htaccess` file exists in the public_html folder, I cannot view the homepage or any other routes.

#### .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsiteurl.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
  
  # If the above doesn't work you might need to set the `RewriteBase` directive manually, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A `404` error does not mean your app can't find `getting-started.phtml` file. This is probably related to the `.htaccess` file. Could you add the content of that file to your question please?

Comment: @Nima thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer. As I explain in the edit, I had actually forgotten to create a symlink for the .htaccess file, but since adding it I cannot even access the homepage and I'm redirected to the default apache page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I had not enabled `mod_rewrite` on the server, so my `.htaccess` file was not being read.